# IIS 504 Gateway_timeout when submitting form (Post)

Tags: angularjs, iis, image-processing, base64, http-post

First of all thank you for your help.

I am using Windows server 2008, IIS 7 and have an angular.js website using POST to submit a json object with form values,  2 of those values are small base64 images, when submitting the form I get a 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT. I have been hitting my head to the wall all day reading and trying to find out why is doing that. From what I am reading it seems that IIS will not accept large amounts of data Posted to the server.

I am submitting about 25,000 characters with the form

Comment: just check server post request maximum data limit and reset to what you want.